# OpenCV in Java: error (N >= K) using kmeans clustering

Tags: java, opencv, k-means

I'm getting an error when using OpenCV's `kmeans` function in Java. Does anyone know what this means?

```
error: (-215) N >= K in function double cv::kmeans(cv::InputArray, int, cv::InputOutputArray, cv::TermCriteria, int, int, cv::OutputArray)
```

My parameters are:

```
Mat labels = new Mat();
int attempts = 3;
Mat centers = new Mat();
TermCriteria criteria = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS + 
    TermCriteria.MAX_ITER,100,0.1);
clusterCount = 14;
```

and samples is a matrix with `26` rows and `6` columns, representing `26` feature vectors each of which contains `6` features.

My function call is

```
Core.kmeans(samples, clusterCount, labels, criteria, attempts, Core.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers );
```

In the error message, `K` is obviously the number of clusters, and one of my guesses was that `N` is the number of rows in samples? But in that case N would clearly be more than `K`.

Hoping someone has encountered this before and knows what this means.

Comment: you need more samples(N) than desired clusters(K). are you sure, you got rows & cols right ?

Comment: I got this error when I didn't initialize the input correctly.

Comment: Here's the answer for the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28114662/opencv-kmeans-n-k-exception-error-215