# OpenCV kmeans: N>=K exception, error (-215)

Tags: opencv, k-means

when I try to use kmeans as such:

```
int K = 4;
Mat labels;
Mat centers;
std::vector<float> values;

// (put a bunch of values into "values" here...)

kmeans(values, K, labels, TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT + TermCriteria::EPS, 10, 1.0), 10, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

I get the error: "error: (-215) N >= K in function kmeans"

values.size() = 360000, so N is clearly greater than K.  What gives? Thanks.

Comment: This may be a stupid comment, but you are using `red_values` instead of `values`.  What is the size of `red_values` for your input?

Comment: That was a Stackoverflow input error! Fixed! Sorry and thanks. :-)

Comment: Hmm... did you check the size of `values` and `K` before `kmeans` was called?  I know you have placed the sizes in your post, but did you physically put in a debug statement or check using the debugger to verify the size of `values` and `K`? That error is only produced if the number of points in your data set is less than the desired number of clusters.  Also, each data point occupies **one row** while each column is a variable.  Are you arranging your data in this fashion?  Are you making sure that **each row** represents a data point?

Comment: Yep - right before kmeans, K == 4 and values == 360000.  And I guess I'm not sure what you mean in your second point.  Values is just a vector...Is there something I need to specify about labels and centers?

Comment: Look at Andrey's comment below.  I thought you were inputting in a matrix, but you were using a `vector` (actually, I missed this from your original post).  You need to change your data so that it becomes a matrix with 1 column.

Comment: That's frustrating, since the documentation says that type InputArray can be a std::vector!!!

Comment: No kidding!  Which version of OpenCV are you using?  I looked at the 2.4.9 docs.

Comment: @kdottiemo it can be `std::vector`. You are just unlucky with `kmeans` function. Say for `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` it will work out of the box even with `kmeans`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV weirdly interprets one-dimensional data as a 1 element array.

Something like following should fix the behavior:

```
kmeans(cv::Mat(values).reshape(1, values.size()), K, labels, TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT + TermCriteria::EPS, 10, 1.0), 10, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

This worked for me.
Converted vector to Mat.

```
int K = 4;
Mat labels;
Mat centers;
std::vector<float> values;
Mat points=Mat(values,true);
points.convertTo(points, CV_32F);
kmeans(points, K, labels, TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT + TermCriteria::EPS, 10, 1.0), 10, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers);
```